# D3.js appending wrong location

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Here is a simplified version of my DOM structure:

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   id=""
   viewBox="0 0 745 471">
  <defs
     id="defs3367" />
  <g
     style="display:inline"
     transform="translate(0,-520.8662)"
     id="items">
    <rect
       ry="0"
       rx="0"
       y="812.9881"
       x="5.7393227"
       height="42.501518"
       width="733.25098"
       id="rect3410">
   </g>
</svg>
```

I have the following D3.js code:

```
var svgBlock = d3.select("svg");
var items =  svgBlock.selectAll("g#items")
                     .data(data)
                     .enter()
                     .append("g");
```

My data is an array of 6 objects.

The issue is that this code appends **5** `<g>` but child to `svg`, not child to the `<g id="item">`.
Also the first item in data simply does not get appended at all.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3` appends to the *selected object* you are calling append on (in this case your `svg` tag).

To append to your target `g` do:

```
svgBlock.select("g#items") //<-- appending to this g
  .selectAll("g") //<-- a selector that matches WHAT you want append
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g");
```

In fact, this should fix your "missing" element as well.  The way your code is currently written, `d3` thinks the `g#items` is one of the six, so it one is not **entering** and is not appended.

Comment: awesome! D3.js selectors are quite confusing to me. Will read more about them.